# Radzen Blazor WebAssemblyApp Slow Problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

my blazor app is running extremely slow. For example, when a dialog is opened, it responds after 4 seconds or when closing, it responds after 4 seconds and does not do anything in the background, only the dialog opens and closes. It's the same even though I tried it on different computers and servers. Even when we want to make a different application, it works slowly, the page loads slowly, the dialogs are slow to open and close. In the picture below, the settings of my blazor application are shown:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Let me show you a page of mine like this:

```
@page "/Pdi"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Services;
@using basicwebasbly.Api;
@using basicwebasbly.Components.Pdi;
@using blazorWebDAL.Models;
@using blazorWebDAL.Models.DbModel;
@inject DialogService dialogService;
<RadzenCard style="display: flex; align-items: center; gap: 0.5rem;background-color:#c6c3c6;">
    <div class="m-auto">
        <RadzenCard class="mx-auto " style="display: flex; text-align:end; align-items:end; gap: 0.6rem;background-color:#c6c3c6;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row float-end">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <RadzenButton Text="Ekle" Style="border-radius:20px;" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Success" Click="@(()=>OpenCustomerOrderDlg(null,"create"))" Icon="add_circle_outline"></RadzenButton>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <RadzenButton Text="Yenile" Style="border-radius:20px;" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Click="@(()=>GetAll())" Icon="refresh"></RadzenButton>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </RadzenCard>
        <RadzenDataGrid @ref="radzenDataGrid"
                        FilterText="Ara..."
                        AllowFiltering="true"                   
                        AllowAlternatingRows="false"
                        FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple"
                        AllowSorting="true"
                        Filter="@OnFilter"
                        AllowPaging="true"
                        PagerHorizontalAlign="HorizontalAlign.Left"
                        Data="@customerOrderDtos"
                        TItem="CustomerOrderDto"
                        Style="background-color:#c6c3c6; --rz-cell-filter-width:20px"
                        GridLines="DataGridGridLines.Both"
                        SelectionMode="DataGridSelectionMode.Single"
                        Density="Density.Compact"
                        RowRender="@RowRender"
                        >
            <Columns>

                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Filterable Property="CustomerOrderId" Title="Bobin Numarası" Width="50px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Property="CustomerOrderStatusName" Title="Bobin Durumu" Width="50px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Property="Name" Title="Kalınlık" Width="50px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Property="Remark" Title="Genişlik" Width="50px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Property="OrderNumber" Title="Ağırlık" Width="50px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Property="OrderNumber" Title="Uzunluk" Width="50px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Property="OrderNumber" Title="İç Çap" Width="50px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Property="OrderNumber" Title="Dış Çap" Width="50px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="CustomerOrderDto" Property="CustomerOrderId" Title="İşlemler" Width="50px">
                    <Template Context="data">
                        <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Warning" Variant="Variant.Flat" Shade="Shade.Lighter" Icon="pageview" class="m-1" Click="@(()=>OpenCustomerOrderDlg(data.CustomerOrderId,"update"))" />
                        <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Variant="Variant.Flat" Shade="Shade.Lighter" Icon="delete" class="m-1" Click="@(()=>DeleteCustomerOrder(data))" />
                        <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Variant="Variant.Flat" Shade="Shade.Lighter" Icon="list" class="m-1" Click="@(()=>ChangePdiStatus(data.CustomerOrderId))" />
                    </Template>
                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            </Columns>
            </RadzenDataGrid>
        </div>
        </RadzenCard>
        @code {
    List<CustomerOrderDto> customerOrderDtos = new List<CustomerOrderDto>();
    RadzenDataGrid<CustomerOrderDto>? radzenDataGrid;
    [Inject]
    CustomerOrderApi customerOrderApi { get; set; }
    public CustomerOrderDto lazyParams = new CustomerOrderDto { };
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetAll();

    }
    async Task OpenCustomerOrderDlg(string customerOrderId, string dlgType)
    {
        DialogOptions dialogOptions = new DialogOptions
            {
                Width = "1000px",
                Height = "650px",
                ShowTitle = true,
            };

        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"CustomerOrderId",customerOrderId},
            {"dlgType",dlgType}
        };
        var dialogTitle = (dlgType == "create" ? "Sipariş Ekle" : (customerOrderId + " Siparişi Düzenle"));
        var obj = await dialogService.OpenAsync<PdiDlg>(dialogTitle, dict, dialogOptions);
        if (true == true)
        {
            await GetAll();
        }

    }
    async Task GetAll()
    {
        customerOrderDtos = await customerOrderApi.GetCustomerOrderList();
    }
    async void DeleteCustomerOrder(CustomerOrderDto customerOrderId)
    {
        var result = await dialogService
        .Confirm(customerOrderId.CustomerOrderId + " bobinini silmek istiyor musunuz?", "Uyarı",
        new ConfirmOptions { OkButtonText="Evet", CancelButtonText="Hayır" });
        if (result == true)
        {
            await customerOrderApi.DeleteCustomerOrder(customerOrderId);
            await GetAll();
        }

    }
    async Task ChangePdiStatus(string coilId)
    {
        DialogOptions dialogOptions = new DialogOptions
            {
                Width = "330px",
                Height = "310px",
                ShowTitle = true,
                CssClass = "rounded-1"
            };
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"coilId",coilId},
        };
        var result = await dialogService.OpenAsync<PdiStatusDlg>("Bobin Durumu Değiştir", dict, dialogOptions);
        if (result == true)
        {
            await GetAll();
        }

    }
    async void OnFilter(DataGridColumnFilterEventArgs<CustomerOrderDto> args)
    {
        lazyParams.Page = 1;
        lazyParams.First = 0;
        lazyParams.Rows = 20;
        lazyParams.TotalRecords=20;
        lazyParams.SortOrder =(int)(args.Column.SortOrder.Value);
        lazyParams.SortField = args.FilterValue.ToString();
        //await GetAll();
    }
    void RowRender(RowRenderEventArgs<CustomerOrderDto> args)
    {
        if (args.Data.CustomerOrderStatusName == "Sipariş Oluşturuldu")
        {
            args.Attributes.Add("style", $"background-color:red");
        }
    }
}
```

Dialog Page:

```
@using Radzen;
@using basicwebasbly.Api;
@using basicwebasbly.Pages;
@using blazorWebDAL.Models;
@inject DialogService dialogService;
<!--<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Subtitle2" TagName="TagName.H3">Sipariş Adı</RadzenText>
            <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value=customerOrderDto.Name />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Subtitle2" TagName="TagName.H3">Sipariş Durumu</RadzenText>
            <CustomerOrderStatusDropDown @bind-customerOrderStatusId=customerOrderDto.CustomerOrderStatusId />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Subtitle2" TagName="TagName.H3">Sipariş Numarası</RadzenText>
            <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value=customerOrderDto.OrderNumber />
            <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Subtitle2" TagName="TagName.H3">Sipariş Açıklaması</RadzenText>
            <RadzenTextArea @bind-Value=customerOrderDto.Remark Cols="30" Rows="3" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
    <FooterTemplate>

            <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" JustifyContent="JustifyContent.End" Gap="0">
                <RadzenButton Variant="Variant.Text" class="rz-text-secondary-color" Click="@CloseDialog" Text="İptal" />
                <RadzenButton Variant="Variant.Text" class="rz-text-secondary-color" Click="@SaveCustomerOrder" Text="Kaydet" />
            </RadzenStack>

    </FooterTemplate>
</div>
</div>-->
<RadzenTemplateForm Data="customerOrderDto">
    <RadzenRow Gap="2rem" Class="rz-p-0 rz-p-lg-4">
        <RadzenColumn Size="8" SizeMD="5">
            <RadzenStack>
                <RadzenFieldset Text="Sipariş Bilgileri">
                    <RadzenStack Gap="1rem">
                        <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="4">
                                <RadzenLabel Text="Sipariş Adı" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="8">
                                <RadzenTextBox Style="width: 100%;" Name="CardNr" @bind-Value=customerOrderDto.Name />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                        </RadzenRow>
                        <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="4">
                                <RadzenLabel Text="Sipariş Numarası" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="8">
                                <RadzenTextBox Style="width: 100%;" @bind-Value=customerOrderDto.OrderNumber />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                        </RadzenRow>
                        <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="4">
                                <RadzenLabel Text="Sipariş Durumu" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="8">
                                <PdiStatusDropdwn @bind-pdiStatusId=customerOrderDto.CustomerOrderStatusId />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                        </RadzenRow>

                        <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="4">
                                <RadzenLabel Text="Sipariş Açıklaması" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="8">
                                <RadzenTextArea Cols="20" Rows="4" @bind-Value="customerOrderDto.Remark" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                        </RadzenRow>
                        <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="4">
                                <RadzenLabel Text="Sipariş Oluşturma Tarihi" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="8">
                                <RadzenDatePicker TValue="DateTime?" Cols="20" Rows="4" @bind-Value="customerOrderDto.CreatedDate" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                        </RadzenRow>

                    </RadzenStack>
                </RadzenFieldset>
            </RadzenStack>
        </RadzenColumn>
        <RadzenColumn Size="8" SizeMD="7">
            <RadzenStack>
                <RadzenFieldset Text="Bobin Bilgileri">
                    <RadzenStack Gap="1rem">

                        <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="4">
                                <RadzenLabel Text="ScheduleId" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                            <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="8">
                                <RadzenTextBox Disabled="true" Placeholder="ScheduleId" Style="width: 100%;" />
                            </RadzenColumn>
                        </RadzenRow>

                    </RadzenStack>
                </RadzenFieldset>

            </RadzenStack>
        </RadzenColumn>


    </RadzenRow>
    <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" JustifyContent="JustifyContent.End" Gap="1rem" Class="rz-mt-8 rz-mb-4">
        <RadzenButton Icon="done" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Success" class="dlgBtn" Click="@SaveCustomerOrder" Text="Kaydet" />
        <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" class="dlgBtn" Click="@CloseDialog" Text="İptal" />
    </RadzenStack>
</RadzenTemplateForm>
<style>
    .dlgBtn {
        border: 1px 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

</style>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string CustomerOrderId { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public string dlgType { get; set; } = "create";

    private CustomerOrderDto customerOrderDto = new CustomerOrderDto { };
    [Inject]
    CustomerOrderApi itemApi { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (dlgType == "create")
        {
            customerOrderDto = new CustomerOrderDto { };
        }
        if (dlgType == "update")
        {
            customerOrderDto = await itemApi.GetCustomerOrder(CustomerOrderId);
        }
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    }
    void CloseDialog()
    {

        dialogService.Close(true);

    }
    async void SaveCustomerOrder()
    {
        customerOrderDto.CustomerId = 1;

        if (dlgType == "create")
        {
            customerOrderDto.CustomerOrderId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            customerOrderDto.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            await itemApi.AddCustomerOrder(customerOrderDto);

        }
        if (dlgType == "update")
        {
            await itemApi.UpdateCustomerOrder(customerOrderDto);
        }
        CloseDialog();
    }

}
```

Not only this page, but all the pages are empty, the page with only one datagrid is loading slowly, I can't solve this slowness.

Comment: Because I use webApi background EF and they do not create a problem, they are not used, they are used in the back and I use the same application I made in Vue.js, the WebApi part can work without any problems.

Comment: There are many reasons can cause your project very slow, Maybe you can refer to [ASP.NET Core Blazor performance best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0).